# Is there a way to use rewrite rules in Wordpress to correctly render a page or post?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I made a Wordpress plugin that was able to rewrite URLs so that users could add a vanity segment at the end of the URL so that every page had personalized information via an external API call with the vanity segment being used as a query parameter. For example https://mywordpress.com/name-of-page/

Without the vanity segment one would simply see the page contents.

https://mywordpress.com/name-of-page/unique-vanity

With the vanity segment one would see the same page as accessed from the first URL, but also additional details based on the data returned from the external API. The problem I have now is that this plugin needs to retain the same functionality for pages as well as posts.

I know that if I use only one rewrite rule I can get the intended outcome.

```
// This will work only for pages
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule('([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&customsegment=$matches[2]','top');
});

OR

// This will work only for posts
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule('([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$','index.php?name=$matches[1]&customsegment=$matches[2]','top');
});
```

It does not seem that on `init` Wordpress knows whether or not the URL is pointing at a page or post (or even what the full URL is going to be yet), so I don't think I can dynamically change the rule here. Instead I have tried the following code, but I am unable to get the page/post template to render correctly.

```
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule('([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$','index.php?contenttitle=$matches[1]&vanity=$matches[2]','top');
});

add_filter('query_vars', function ($qvars) {
  $qvars[] = 'contenttitle';
  $qvars[] = 'vanity';
  return $qvars;
});

function custom_rewrite_template_include($template) {
  if (get_query_var('contenttitle')) {
      $title = get_query_var('contenttitle');
      $vanity = get_query_var('vanity');

      $page = get_page_by_path($title);
      $post = get_page_by_path($title, OBJECT, 'post');
      
      if ($page) {
          $page_temp = get_page_template();
          return $page_temp;
      } elseif ($post) {
          $post_temp = get_template_part('content', 'single');
          return $post_temp;
      }
  }
  
  return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'custom_rewrite_template_include');
```

It is unclear to me what the exact issue is, but it looks like I am just seeing an `index.php` with a list of posts and never the single page or post that should be associated with the URL. I believe with this approach I would also need to flush the rewrite rules programmatically because the rule should change whether a page or post is being accessed.

Comment: maybe you just need to flush the rewrite rules table with `flush_rewrite_rules()` or simply open Settings > permalinks form and save.

Comment: That is required when changing the rewrite rules, but that is not the problem I have. Even if I flush the rules through the Wordpress admin settings I still have this same issue of not being able to dynamically rewrite rules based on whether a page or post is being accessed.

Comment: I have somewhat similar process with the only difference to yours is it all runs within the `init` hook. Note that `get_query_var` only run in `the_loop` to output content.The condition I use is to test the `rewrite_rules` table for my entry. eg: `$rules = get_option('rewrite_rules', []);` then test `if( isset($rules['site-admin/?$']) ) $dotemplateChange`